# Alternative of canopy clustering algorithm in K-means algorithm

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am analyzing implementation of K-means clustering algorithm in MadLib project. Here K-means algorithm uses Canopy clustering for initial set of Centroid.I am just wondering , are there any other clustering algorithm, that can be used at place of Canopy for better performance?
Below is the link for details description of Canopy Clustering.
[canopy clustering](https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/canopy-clustering.html)

Comment: There are several k-means algorithms. Can you define the Canopy algorithm you are referring to & what's wrong with it?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it, i am just wants to make it more efficient and fast. Here is the link for canopy algorithm.

Comment: i have updated the question with link.

Answer (score 1):

A popular initialization for k-means is k-means++.

It chooses initial seeds randomly, weighted by their distance from the previous choices. I.e. it prefers objects that are further apart.